# WCF unknown field ExtensionData

Tags: c#, wcf

I have this class **Schedule** which I return from a WCF function. When I add the service reference in visual studio, I'm unable to see the StartTime and EndTime properties instead I get this weird ExtensionData field. Can any one explain why this is happening?

```
public class Schedule
{
    public Duration SDuration
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public Timeslot STimeslot
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class Timeslot
{
    public DateTime StartTime;
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public DateTime EndTime;
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public bool SomeFunc()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these the full class declarations? I would have expected to see some `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes.

Comment: Yep, these are the full class declarations. Won't it work without DataContract?

Comment: The `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes control the serialization of the objects, so you should definitely decorate the classes that are exposed through the service with those attributes.

Comment: They are not required if you are using .NET 3.5 SP1 but for best practice, you should definitely include them.

Answer (score 0):

As Fredrik mentioned in the comment, the classes must be decorated with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

...because you didn't specified the DataContract attribute, by default it used the Serializable attribute. the serializable attribute then includes all the Fields you got in your class (none, as those are properties), therefore those property information are stored in the ExtensionData.